# MLKit Android : crash when using text recognition

Tags: java, android, crash, google-mlkit, text-recognition

Some time ago, I started a new feature, allowing you to read the MRZ strip of an ID card.
However, I wanted to re-test this feature and it no longer works.

I get different errors depending on what I'm using :

> ```
> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:19.0.0'
> ```

```
Text recognition failed
 com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Failed to init text recognizer play-services-mlkit-text-recognition
    at com.google.mlkit.vision.text.internal.zzc.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common@@19.0.0:5)
    at com.google.mlkit.vision.text.internal.TextRecognizerTaskWithResource.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common@@19.0.0:2)
    at com.google.mlkit.vision.text.internal.TextRecognizerTaskWithResource.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common@@19.0.0:1)
    at com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.MobileVisionBase.zza(com.google.mlkit:vision-common@@17.3.0:2)
    at com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.zza.call(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.ModelResource.zza(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.8.0:8)
    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzn.run(Unknown Source:10)
    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzt.run(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.8.0:2)
    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zze(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.8.0:4)
    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzc(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.8.0:1)
    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzk.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzd(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.8.0:2)
    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzi.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
 Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Failed to initialize TfLite-GMS
    at m.vd.c(:com.google.android.gms.optional_mlkit_ocr_common@234414042@23.44.14 (100400-0):279)
    at m.bly.a(:com.google.android.gms.optional_mlkit_ocr_common@234414042@23.44.14 (100400-0):112)
    at m.bp.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.optional_mlkit_ocr_common@234414042@23.44.14 (100400-0):21)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:914)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.mlkit_vision_text_common.zza.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common@@19.0.0:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.mlkit_vision_text_common.zzrw.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common@@19.0.0:2)
    at com.google.mlkit.vision.text.internal.zzc.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common@@19.0.0:3)
    at com.google.mlkit.vision.text.internal.TextRecognizerTaskWithResource.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common@@19.0.0:2) 
    at com.google.mlkit.vision.text.internal.TextRecognizerTaskWithResource.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common@@19.0.0:1) 
    at com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.MobileVisionBase.zza(com.google.mlkit:vision-common@@17.3.0:2) 
    at com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.zza.call(Unknown Source:4) 
    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.ModelResource.zza(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.8.0:8) 
    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzn.run(Unknown Source:10) 
    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzt.run(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.8.0:2) 
    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zze(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.8.0:4) 
    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzc(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.8.0:1) 
    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzk.run(Unknown Source:2) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzd(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.8.0:2) 
    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzi.run(Unknown Source:2) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.DelegateLastClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000013b/dl-MlkitOcrCommon.optional_234414100400.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000013b/dl-MlkitOcrCommon.optional_234414100400.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000013b/dl-MlkitOcrCommon.optional_234414100400.apk!/lib/armeabi, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]] couldn't find "libmlkit_google_ocr_pipeline_gms.so"
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1067)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1007)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1667)
```

If I use the bundled version like this with this dependency :

> implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition:16.0.0'

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/APPNAME-HMyTa1XfEYw4eV3v5DEB_w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/APPNAME-HMyTa1XfEYw4eV3v5DEB_w==/lib/arm, /data/app/APPNAME-HMyTa1XfEYw4eV3v5DEB_w==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]] couldn't find "libmlkit_google_ocr_pipeline.so"
```

Any idea about what is causing theses issues ? The code was working, and a day without modification on my part it no longer works.

I searched on the GitHub Issue page of the project, but can't find any solution.

Comment: Seems to be internal to the library. Have you tried debugging what is going on inside of it during init?